# Launch app only in single instance and kill/prevent other instances if started

Tags: android, android-intent

Let's take an example:

**Scenario:**
I am trying to book a movie ticket using a mobile application and at the time of payment, the app provides me to select any of the payment apps (already installed in my phone) to complete the payment. I select my mobile app, which is a payment app and it gets opened inside the movie ticket booking application.

**Problem Statment:**
The problem is that if my payment app's instance is already running inside the movie ticket booking application, and I minimize it and go launch my payment app separately, it still opens leaving me with two instances running:

1. My payment app running inside the movie ticket booking app.
2. My App running separately.

I want that at a time only one instance should live and if someone launches the app separately it should get redirect to the living/running instance.

**Note:** I have tried using `android:launchMode="singleTask"` but still facing the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is *how* you loading your service when you call purchase. What type of navigation do you use? Is it possible to use fragmentManager instead of start Activity?
Please send pic of your navigation call code